# Decorating a inherited mixin method as a pyqtSlot

Tags: python, qml, pyqt5, decorator, slot

I have a LogMixIn class. I want to create a Logger class that I can expose to QML for my QML to use. Since all the methods I want to use are from LogMixIn, is there a way to decorate inherited methods instead of having to redefine them like I do in the example below?

**my_logging_lib.py**

```py
class LogMixIn():

    def logDebug(self, msg):
        # Log msg at Debug Severity
```

**qml_logger.py**

```py
from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject, pyqtSlot
from my_logging_lib import LogMixIn

class QmlLogger(QObject, LogMixIn):

    @pyqtSlot(str)
    def logDebug(self, msg):
        super().logDebug(msg)
```

***note 1:*** LogMixIn is use in a large portion of non-UI code so it's desireable to keep it QT agnostic.

Comment: @eyllanesc, that is correct. The above implementation works fine, and seems correct, but conceptually it seemed like there would be another way to do it in a clean, compact way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PyQt5, `pyqtSlot` **can** decorate methods of classes that do not inherit from `QObject`, such as ordinary Python mixin classes. You can easily check this by examining the [meta-object](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#metaObject) of a subclass that inherits such a mixin:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot, QObject, QMetaMethod

class LogMixIn:
    def logDebug(self, msg):
        pass

    @pyqtSlot(str)
    def logDebugEx(self, msg):
        pass

class QmlLogger(QObject, LogMixIn):
    @pyqtSlot(str)
    def logDebug(self, msg):
        super().logDebug(msg)

foo = QmlLogger()

meta = foo.metaObject()

for index in range(meta.methodCount()):
    method = meta.method(index)
    if method.methodType() == QMetaMethod.Slot:
        print(method.methodSignature())
```

Output:

```
b'deleteLater()'
b'_q_reregisterTimers(void*)'
b'logDebug(QString)'
b'logDebugEx(QString)'
```

As you can see, it makes no difference how the slots are defined. This is because PyQt does not need to check the type of the containing class until an actual connection is made. If the receiver is found to be a `QObject` at that time, PyQt can create an internal proxy `QObject` with a slot that can be used by Qt. For QML, the only thing that matters is that the methods are accessible via the meta-object system so that they can be called via e.g. [invokeMethod](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetaobject.html#invokeMethod).

Note that `pyqtSignal` and `pyqtProperty` can also be used in mixins. However, this behaviour was only introduced in PyQt5, so it won't work at all in PyQt4. I believe that similar behaviour is found in all versions of PySide, though.

**UPDATE**:

If you cannot decorate the mixin directly, the slots can be created within the subclass definition like this:

```
class QmlLogger(QObject, LogMixIn):
    logDebug = pyqtSlot(str)(LogMixIn.logDebug)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. It's good to know that methods can be decorated before instantiating a concrete QObject subclass. However it seems my original question may have been a bit vague. The LogMixIn resides in a separate file, which would be best kept QT agnostic. My original question has been updated to reflect this.

Comment: thank you for the update, that's exactly the kind of solution I was looking for.